# Issue with columns + carousel not equal in height in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, media-queries

I hope someone can help me out with a Bootstrap 3 problem I am experiencing.

A screenshot explains the problem way better, than I can explain in English. So, please, see below.

[image: Bootstrap 3 colum equal/matching height problem]

As you can see I have 2 columns on the left side and 1 on the right together with the Bootstrap carousel. But the problem is, I am getting empty (white) space under the left column.

I would like the right column + carousel match the left columns in height. So everything is aligned. The left columns have the correct height (there is already text content in them in my real design). I think this should be possible, but I have no clue on how to achieve this.

I tried several weird things myself, though it works for one browser, it obviously doesn't work for the other. So I am looking for a solution for this. I think it's possible by making some changes to the carousel?

Since this is only a (small) part of the full website I am working on, I will paste the necessary code. Maybe someone can take a look and come up with a solution or idea?

(please ignore the inline stuff, I am still testing some stuff before I add classes to them)

Partial HTML code:

```
<div class="row clearfix no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-7 column">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <div class="box-contents fontsize938">
                        <div style="float:right;font-size:0.938em;padding-top:10px;color:#777;">subtitleright</div>
                        <img src="images/mini_logo.png" width="21" height="22" class="minilogo" alt=""/><h4>Header</h4>
                        <div class="multiColumn">
                        <ul class="webss">
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div style="height:22px;padding:2px 8px 0 7px;">
                            <div style="float:left;"><a class="weblink" href="info.php" title="Ipsum Lorem stuff" target="_parent"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Ipsum Lorem stuff</a></div>
                            <div style="float:right;"><a class="weblink" href="best.php" title="Ipsum Lorem stuff" target="_parent"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Ipsum Lorem stuff</a></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <div class="box-contents fontsize938">
                        <div style="float:right;font-size:0.938em;padding-top:10px;color:#777;">subtitleright</div>
                        <img src="images/mini_logo.png" width="21" height="22" class="minilogo" alt=""/><h4>Header</h4>
                        <div class="multiColumn">
                        <ul class="webss">
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play smallglyph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ipsum Lorem stuff</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div style="height:22px;padding:2px 8px 0 7px;">
                            <div style="float:left;"><a class="weblink" href="info.php" title="Ipsum Lorem stuff" target="_parent"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Ipsum Lorem stuff</a></div>
                            <div style="float:right;"><a class="weblink" href="best.php" title="Ipsum Lorem stuff" target="_parent"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Ipsum Lorem stuff</a></div>
                        </div>  
                </div>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <form method="post" action="req.php" id="checkd1" class="formd">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <span class="input-group-addon broundleft"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="webbb" placeholder="Ipsum Lorem stuff">
                    <input type="hidden" name="request" value="single">
                    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary broundright" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> &nbsp;Check!</button></span>
                </div>                
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <div id="carousel-index" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active"><img src="images/gallery1.jpg" alt="Ipsum Lorem stuff"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="images/gallery2.jpg" alt="Ipsum Lorem stuff"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="images/gallery3.jpg" alt="Ipsum Lorem stuff"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Carousel CSS:

```
.carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img{
display:block;
height:auto;
max-width:100%;
line-height:1;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
border-radius:6px; 
-moz-border-radius:6px; 
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-khtml-border-radius:6px;
border:1px solid #fff;
}
.carousel{
border-radius:6px; 
-moz-border-radius:6px; 
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-khtml-border-radius:6px;
border:1px solid #d5d5d5;
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #e1e1e1;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #e1e1e1;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #e1e1e1;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

If you need more stuff from me please ask. I am already glad that you are taking a look at this. Many thanks in advance...!

//UPDATE #1

As requested I created (my first) JSFiddle, which is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3pc7rm/1/

You have to resize the windows width (to a maximum) to see the problem I am experiencing. Also on smaller sizes the carousel is not matched to the left columns.

//UPDATE #2

Well I tried several solutions which are found on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, but non are working. I also tried setting "max-height:332px;" to the carousel. This works, but very limited. In Firefox it works, but other browsers not (size mismatch due to HTML/CSS probably). Also when window size becomes smaller the height is even more off (= smaller).

I wish someone could provide a working solution whatsoever, maybe even by using javascript?

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your partial code including the relevant CSS (http://jsfiddle.net) ???

Comment: Never used JSFiddle before, but I managed to add it. Hope this helps to provide a solution for this issue. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3pc7rm/3/.

Since Bootstrap sets the carousel image height to `auto` in order to allow it to expand according to its aspect ratio. Hence, you have to fix the height of the carousel image so that it won't change with the screen resize. For this, just add following media query in your CSS,

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){
.carousel-inner>.item>img, 
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img{
    height: 295px;    
}  
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
.carousel-inner>.item>img, 
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img{
    height: 295px;    
}  
}
```

Although this might result in stretching of the image, but it would achieve what you want.

<-----UPDATE----->

Here is a `jquery` solution, check out the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3pc7rm/6/

Just include `jquery` and this code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 992px)').matches || window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1200px)').matches) {
            var newHeight = $('#col7').outerHeight() - $('#row1').outerHeight() - 10;
            $('#carousel-index .item img').css('height',newHeight+'px');
        }
        else{
            $('#carousel-index .item img').css('height','auto');
        }
    });
    $(window).resize();
});
```

`window.matchMedia()` is fully consistent with the CSS media queries and the browser support is quite good. Although, it doesn't support IE9.

Comment: I just checked your fiddle, however it's still not aligned correctly. And even worse, it looks different in 2 browsers (FF, IE). So thank you for looking into this, however this is a solution. It's kinda similar to what I have posted on update #2.

Comment: Awesome man!! Thank you so much. I also tried some (examples) with JS, however it didn't work, but that's probably because I don't understand JS at all. So thank you so much. And to be honest; I don't care about IE9 or lower. Thank you once again!

Comment: Well I applied it to my website and it works. There is only one minor downside (with IE11). It takes about 2 seconds before the column is resized. This does not happen in FF, Chrome, etc. I already tried placing the jquery and JS in the head section, but that didn't improve it. But like I said; it's a minor issue. Is there a way to speed it up? If not, no worries. I already appreciate your help so far! :))

Comment: Will look into this issue ASAP. I guess that's why global usage of IE is only around 7%...:P

Comment: Did you have the time to look into this by any chance? Like I said it's not a really big deal, but if there is a fix, I would appreciate it ofcourse. :)

Comment: are you still alive? Would appreciate any input on this (small) issue. TY

Comment: Sorry...was not active for a while...why don't you give it a default height according to IE11 so that it would look good even in IE11 and no resize will be visible

Comment: Uhmz... That might be an idea. If it's close enough, people wouldn't notice the height change. Good thinking.

Can I use this to target IE10+

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
/* IE10+ specific styles go here */  
}

Comment: yeah...that looks great as far as IE10+ is concerned and can really solve your problem too.

Comment: maybe you can use the ie slash-9 property hack in conjunction with it. @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) { .selector { property:value\9; } }

Comment: Well tried several things including: @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) { #carousel-index { max-height:200px !important;max-height:200px\9 !important; } }

But it didn't work. Seems to ignore it completely. Doesn't matter what ID or CLASS I select for it. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: well, try doing this: @media screen\0 {  #carousel-index { max-height:200px !important;} }

Comment: Man... I am an idiot. :| I was refreshing the page with Firefox. Sorry... It works like it should thank you! And once again sorry for me being so damn stupid!! :|